# Изменить размер шрифта ActionBar

Tags: android

Так получаю и изменяю сам шрифт в ActionBar

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(getTitle());
s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, "Dolores.otf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
actionBar.setTitle(s);
```

А как изменить размер шрифта?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете это сделать, но не стоит, так как размер шрифта стандартизирован (что соответствует гайдлайнам).

Если вы все же хотите изменить размер шрифта, то вы можете использовать кастомизированную пользовательскую тему или, возможно, реализовать форк ActionBar (как сделано [здесь](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar)).

Вариант со стилями и темами:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/titleStyle</item>
</style>
<!-- ActionBar title styles -->
<style name="titleStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: поняла, спасибо